# defaultMinPartitions in textFile

Tags: apache-spark

I started to use spark on yarn recently and found a problem while tuning my program.

When `SparkContext` is initialized as `sc` and ready to read text file from hdfs, the `textFile(path, defaultMinPartitions)` method is called.
I traced down the second parameter in the spark source code and finally found this:
   `conf.getInt("spark.default.parallelism", math.max(totalCoreCount.get(), 2))`  in  `CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.scala`

I do not specify the property `“spark.default.parallelism”` anywhere so the `getInt` will return value from the larger one between `totalCoreCount` and 2.

When I submit the application using `spark-submit` and specify the parameter: `--num-executors  2   --executor-cores 6`, I suppose the `totalCoreCount` will be 
2*6 = 12, so `defaultMinPartitions` will be 12.

But when I print the value of `defaultMinPartitions` in my program, I still get 2 in return,  How does this happen, or where do I make a mistake?

Answer (score 4):

In SparkContext.scala:

```
def defaultMinPartitions: Int = math.min(defaultParallelism, 2)
```

You tracked down the calculation of `defaultParallelism`. It should indeed be 12 in your case. So `defaultMinPartitions` becomes 2.

In the end you should not try to set `defaultMinPartitions`. Instead specify an explicit partition count for the operations that create RDDs.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I thought It was math.max instead of math.min.

Comment: But the question is, why does  spark use defaultMinPartitions , not default_MAX_Partitions?  I did an experiment using a small data file of 2 blocks on hdfs, each block about 60MB.  I conducted the test on 10 nodes, each with 64GB ram and 8 cores. A short program had been run twice with the same configuration of --num-executors 2, --executor-cores 6. The only difference is, I first run the program without specify the defaultMinPartitions, total running time is 15mins; then specify the defaultMinPartitions = 12, total time 4mins. What's happening here?

Comment: I'm not sure how you specified `defaultMinPartitions`. Sounds like it succeeded in increasing the number of partitions (you can check `rdd.partitions.length`). With more partitions, more cores will be used in parallel, speeding up the computation.

Comment: `val data = sc.textFile(path, 12)`

Comment: If increasing the `defaultMinPartitions` will potentially lead to computation speed up, why spark choose a smaller value between `(defaultParallelism, 2)`?

Comment: Good question. I think a higher value may lead to more IO and bandwidth use. With 12 partitions and 2 HDFS blocks, you are going to read each block 6 times, which is wasteful in some sense. But you could ask on the `users@spark.apache.org` mailing list. Looks like this formula has been unchanged since 2011. Could be time for a second look.

Comment: Thank you for your instruction, it helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I found the comment in code (at SparkContext.scala), which might explain why min value was used:

> Default min number of partitions for Hadoop RDDs when not given by
>   user    Notice that we use math.min so the "defaultMinPartitions"
>   cannot be higher than 2.    The reasons for this are discussed in

https://github.com/mesos/spark/pull/718